# Python how to add a new property on a subclass

Tags: python

I created a class **Server** implementing `socketserver.BaseRequestHandler`.

I'm looking to add a `self.buffer = ''` attribute.

Here is the code I came up with :

```
class Server(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

  def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
    super(Server, self).__init__(request=request, client_address=client_address, server=server)
    self.buffer = ''

  def get_first_buffer(self):
    self.buffer = 'Successfully connected.'

  def handle(self):
    if self.buffer == '':
        self.get_first_buffer()
        print(self.buffer)
```

Here is the error I got

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 33564)
AttributeError: 'Server' object has no attribute 'buffer'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When initializing `BaseRequestHandler`, it actually calls `handle`, which means that `self.buffer` must be set before then in order for the `if self.buffer == ''` check to work:

```py
def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
  # move this before the super init
  self.buffer = ''
  super(Server, self).__init__(request=request, client_address=client_address, server=server)
```